# url rewrite in htaccess with variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a url that can have two elements: 1. TYPE 2. LOCATION. Here is the url with no formatting:
`list-hotels-ai.php`
I would like to rewrite the url with htaccess, but I have run into a problem. Sometimes the url will have:
`list-hotels-ai.php?c=Cancun` OR `list-hotels-ai.php?c=Cancun&t=AllInclusive`

I wanted to rewrite the url to be:
`list-hotels-ai.php?c=Cancun` TO `cancun-hotels.php` 
`list-hotels-ai.php?c=Cancun&t=AllInclusive` TO `all-inclusive-cancun-hotels.php`

Does anyone have any idea how to do this via htaccess? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: What rules do you have? Can you include them?

Comment: I have nothing yet... :(

Comment: Whitney, read the FAQ on posing Qs.  Most respondents expect you to add least show that you've done some basic research and tried a few things before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Make a html page that does the redirect using JavaScript.